# How to communicate a future or lazy collection among dask distributed workers

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

The setup is basically:

client side:

```
with Client(...):
    dfs= [client.submit(load_data_lazily, i) for i in ...]
    ddf = dd.from_delayed(dfs)
    xxx = ... how to serialize the handle to ddf ...?
          ... or xxx could be a future instead of a dask collection ...        
    result = client.submit(do_something_with_lazy_remotely, xxx)
```

worker (worker-client) side:

```
def do_something_with_lazy_remotely(xxx):
    with worker_client() as client:
        ddf = ... how to deserialize from xxx and not materialize? ...
        # slice to a reasonable size
        df = client.compute(ddf.loc[...], sync=True)
        # do some computation on df
        client.submit(...)
```

I can get something working by using `client.persist` and `client.publish_dataset`. The problem is then I'm doing manual tracking to figure out when to `unpublish_dataset`, and with asynchronous behavior this gets difficult.

Is there a (more) natural way to do this right now?

EDIT: it seems like [this](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channels.html) may be the way to go here?

Comment: I think that the most natural way to do this would be to make futures serializable.  Then you would just pass the collection through to the submit call natively.  We're getting fairly close to this in PR [dask/distributed # 1201](https://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/1201) , which is partially motivated by other issues that you've raised recently.

Comment: @MRocklin - exciting and awesome

Comment: I've just added this in https://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/1201/commits/e9e18848990910d090f98af2ef0611646f2f14bf